# Cannot uninstall Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

When I'm trying to uninstall Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2, the window with "Please wait while SQL Server 2008 R2 Setup processes the current operation" pops up and stays forever.

I've found solutions to this problem but it was when someone was trying to install server, but not uninstall.

Have anyone faced the similar problem and managed to fix it?

Thank you.

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove all SQL SERVER 2008 R2 services from the command prompt ( Run as Administrator) using the below command :-
sc delete service_name

It did worked for me.

You can get the SQL related services info from services.msc

Answer (score 0):

Following this [MSDN](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/955396) link, you can try to locate the problem in SQL log file. With more information it will be much easier to find solution, or specify your question more accurately.